# Why is it that fragile objects can penetrate much sturdier objects during extreme weather

Tags: weather

I understand that the high wind speed can accelerate said objects to immense velocities but I do not understand why do not fragile objects simply get destroyed upon impact?

Comment: Well, most of them do get destroyed…

Comment: You should probably include examples.